# SFINAE with operator<<

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, sfinae

This program demonstrate two tries to use SFINAE. One works as expected and the other doesn't:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Example {
    typedef int type;
};

template <typename T>
void foo(typename T::type t) {
    cout << "Function 1 is called" << endl;
}

template <typename T>
void foo(T t) {
    cout << "Function 2 is called" << endl;
}

class Stream {
public:
    template <typename T>
    Stream& operator <<(typename T::type t) {
        cout << "Function 3 is called" << endl;
        return *this;
    }

    template <typename T>
    Stream& operator <<(T t) {
        cout << "Function 4 is called" << endl;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    // SFINAE works as expected
    foo<Example>(10);   // Prints "Function 1 is called"
    foo<int>(10);       // Prints "Function 2 is called"

    // SFINAE doesn't work as expected
    Stream strm;
    strm << Example();  // Prints "Function 4 is called"
    strm << 10;         // Prints "Function 4 is called"

    return 0;
}
```

The output is, as noted:

> Function 1 is called
>
> Function 2 is called
>
> Function 4 is called
>
> Function 4 is called

Can someone please explain why the line

> strm << Example();

doesn't print "Function 3 is called"? and what should I do to make it happen?

Comment: because `T::type` is not `T` in this case?

Comment: With `foo<Example>` you tell the compile that `T` is `Example`. With the `operator<<` it has to figure that out all by itself, and cannot find `T::type`.

Comment: Damn... it's sound so simple when you say it... Tnx @BoPersson!